# Set up Java Swing project w/ JUnit/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, junit

This is for a desktop GUI application.  I need to store my Java classes and JUnit test classes in two separate folders.

How do I go about doing this in Eclipse, rather what is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two different *projects* for swings and test cases. Because I feel that it separates the functionality.  Don't write anything under default package, as it is said that its not a good practice.

Comment: No my question is whether Src and Test should be different packages or should come under one package i mean what is the standard convention.

Comment: Ohk. You can have different projects for swing-related and test-related. As, it can separate the functionality. Once if you need to finalize your code, you can just have application without including test cases in it.

Comment: What about creating test classes and main classes under src folder under default package?

Answer (score 0):

I like mavens folder structure. src/main/java and src/test/java

Then use the same package names in each folder so the unit test class has access to the variables in your class.

in eclipse it can generate a unit test class for you. definitely use different folders though so when you package your code you can easily leave the tests out.